# Assign Tasks to Employees evenly skipping rows that already have data

Tags: excel

I have 4 employees that I want to assign studies to (F8:F11). New studies are automatically pulled into the excel sheet. Some of the studies are already assigned because they have worked on them before (column B). Currently I have to manually assign the rest of the tasks (column D) and they whichever one is filled goes into column E. This is the only part of the process that is manual.

I wanted to figure out a way to assign the rest of the studies so the number of studies would come out evenly. I used a the formula below which essential lists employees sequentially (jake, shannon, allison, nat). However, I do not need this done if there is already an assignment in column C. I adapted the formula to account for this. Now it enters them down in order but skips the rows already assigned. So  This led to Allison having 5 studies whereas Jake and Nat only have 1. Row 4 and Row 8 would have been Jake but they were already assigned. I would like it to only assign the columns not already assigned, but use all of the 4 employees.  [Spreadsheet Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v81vz.png)

Is there a way to ensure that tasks are auto assigned without skipping a person in the blank rows?

=IF(C2="",INDEX($F$8:$F$11,MOD(ROW(),4)+1), "")

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you are intending to accomplish. Please add images, with any markup that you think may provide additional context for those wanting to help you out.

Comment: I updated it :) thank you.